# SSH Shell Script multiple commands output

Tags: shell, ssh

Grettings,

I want to execute 2 commands on ssh within a shell script and retrieve the output to my local machine

example

ssh user@host "command1" > /local/1.txt

ssh user@host "command2" > /local/2.txt

I want this but with a single connection is it possible

please don't answer with "Expect" solutions...

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind to use the same file for storing the output; then:

```
ssh user@host "command1; command2" > /local/1-2.txt
```

If it matters, then try something like this:

```
ssh user@host "command1 > /somepath/1.txt; command2 > /somepath/2.txt; ..."
scp user@host:/somepath/*.txt somelocalpath/
```

If you still want just a single connection, maybe this might work for you:

```
ssh user@host "command1; echo "this_is_a_separator"; command2" > /local/1-2.txt
sed -n '1,/this_is_a_separator/ {p}' /local/1-2.txt > /local/1.txt
sed -n '/this_is_a_separator/,$ {p}' /local/1-2.txt > /local/2.txt
```

The local file splitting can be done in several other ways, that was just one of them.

Comment: that sed command isn't good because it leaves the separator on both files and the line breaks :P

Comment: Be careful if the output of command1 does not end with a new line: you could have the separator at the end of a data line.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: not working if the output of `command1` does not end with a new line.

**Edit**: also not working if one or both commands do not produce output.  Needing a more flexible tool --> awk.  See other solution.

To do the same as:

```
ssh user@host "command1" > /local/1.txt
ssh user@host "command2" > /local/2.txt
```

in a single connection, and without temporary file, you could do:

```
ssh user@host "command1 | sed -e 's/^/1/' ; command2 | sed -e 's/^/2/'" | \
sed -n -e '/^1/{s/^.//;w /local/1.txt
};/^2/{s/^.//;w /local/2.txt
}'
```

You need the new lines after `/local/1.txt` and `/local/2.txt`, because if they are not there, sed will keep thinking you are writing a filename.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous solution with sed is broken because of end of line handling, this solution uses awk.

So to do the same as:

```
ssh user@host "command1" > /local/1.txt
ssh user@host "command2" > /local/2.txt
```

in a single connection, and without temporary file, you could do:

```
ssh user@host "command1 | sed -e 's/^/1/'; echo -e '\na'; command2 | sed -e 's/^/2/'; echo" | \
awk -v f1=/local/1.txt -v f2=/local/2.txt \
'BEGIN{state=0; printf "" > f1}
/^1/ {printf "%s%s", state == 1 ? "\n" : "", substr($0, 2) > f1; state=1}
/^$/ && state == 1 {printf "\n" > f1}
/^a$/ {state=2; close (f1); printf "" > f2}
/^2/ {printf "%s%s", state == 3 ? "\n" : "", substr($0, 2) > f2; state=3}
/^$/ && state == 3 {printf "\n" > f2}
END{close (f2)}'
```